# mouse over handler for javascript

Tags: javascript, html

This is my mouse over function when an user hover over an image and it executes this function in html: `onmouseover="big(this)`

whereas this is my javascript code:

```
   function big(x)
    { 
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src="images/related-large2.jpg";
        img.width= 200;
        img.height= 200;
        document.body.appendChild(img);
    }
```

how can i append the child image in reference to the point where i hover over the image instead of appending the image to all the way at the bottom of the page?

Comment: It is ambiguous where exactly you want the new image to be. Are you concerned solely with inserting the image directly into the DOM at or near the `onmouseover` triggering element? Or are you purely concerned with *visually* positioning the new image on the screen?

Comment: appending an image would be my first priority. the position would be the next.

Answer (score 0):

you need to get the x and y coordinates of the event and set the top and left properties of the image to this. To do this, you need to be passing the vent to the function. I've noticed that you arent actually using the object that you are passing in but have included it anyway.

```
<div onmouseover="big(event, this)">
hello
</div>

<script>
function big(e, obj)
    { 
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src="images/related-large2.jpg";
        img.width= 200;
        img.height= 200;
        var x = e.clientX;
                var y = e.clientY;
                img.style.position = 'absolute';
                img.style.top = y + 'px';
                img.style.left = x + 'px';
        document.body.appendChild(img);
    }
</script>
```

[See example](https://jsfiddle.net/whs01u3o/)

Comment: wheres the image src? from your codes i dont think anything is printed too.

Comment: do you really need the event parameter?

Answer (score 0):

```
img.style.top=800;
img.style.right=100;
where.parentNode.appendChild(img);
```